# Move/merge yet-to-be approved topic into newly created one

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-drafts

I have submitted [a new topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/57574) several days ago, and today I noticed that another topic with the same name was created yesterday. The same with [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/57862) too.

Should I retract those submissions and copy paste those examples to the newly created topic or this will be automatically merged when approved?

*I didn't find any move option for yet-to-be-approved topics*